# Difference between interrupt context and process context?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

What is interrupt context ? What is process context ?
What are the advantages of interrupt context ?

Why bottom half required ? Why not all the processing in top half ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can the linux bottom halfs execute in interrupt context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258333/how-can-the-linux-bottom-halfs-execute-in-interrupt-context)

Comment: @Tsyvarev no its different question, it is answer for in which bottom half, interrupt context comes into the picture, and my question is difference between interrupt context and process context.

Comment: Your original question was "Top Halves and bottom Halves. In which type, Interrupt context is comes into the picture?".

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I modified the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Process context is the current state of process, process context can be go into the sleep, preemptable, It perform time consumable task, acquiring and releasing mutex.

Interrupt context is when the interrupt occurs state/priority goes to interrupt handler, and current process stops/saves until we complete interrupt, Interrupt context is not time consumable, non preemptable, It cannot go into the sleep.

Bottom Half mechanism, SoftIRQ, Tasklet works in a interrupt context, workqueue can go into the sleep, so it is not run in interrupt context.

### Process Context

One of the most important parts of a process are the executing program code. This code was read in from a executable file and executed within the program's address space. Normal program execution occurs in User-space. When a program executes a system call or triggers an exception, it enters Kernel-space. At this point, the kernel are said to being "executing on behalf of the process" and are in process context. When in process context, the current macro is valid. Upon exiting the kernel, the process resumes execution in User-space, unless a higher-priority process have become runnable In the interim (transition period), in which case the scheduler is invoked to select the higher priority process.

### Interrupt Context

When executing a interrupt handler or bottom half, the kernel is in interrupt context.Recall That process context is the mode of operation the kernel are in while it's executing on behalf of a process-- For example, executing a system call or running a kernel thread. In process context, the current macro points to the associated task. Furthermore, because a process is coupled to the kernel in process context (because the process is connected to the kernel in the same way as the process above), process context can SleeP or otherwise invoke the scheduler.

Interrupt context, on the other hand, was not associated with a process. The current macro isn't relevant (although it points to the interrupted process). Without a backing process (because there is no process background), interrupt context cannot sleep-how would it ever reschedule? (or how to reschedule it again?) Therefore, cannot call certain functions from interrupt context. If A function sleeps, you cannot use it from your interrupt handler--this limits the functions so one can call from an Interrupt handler. (This is the limit on what functions can be used in an interrupt handler)

[Link](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/summary-of-process-context-and-interrupt-context_8_8_30142056.html) for more details.